# get a date for each week at a specific hour

Tags: php, date, datetime

I would like to generate each dates (timestamp) that start now, on every monday, at a specific time, say 16h30, 17h00 and 14h00.

This code almost works, but the hour is the current one, instead of `$hours[$i]`, and it's also the current day of the week instead of the next monday

```
$hours = array('16h30', '17h00', '14h00');
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    // how to specify the hour $hours[$i] ?
    $dates[] = strtotime("+$i weeks 0 days");
}
```

Desired output:

```
monday 5 november, 16h30
monday 12 november, 16h30
monday 19 november, 16h30
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the 'h' from the times, PHP will understand them as-is, and you can just put the weekday name in the string.

```
$hours = array('1630', '1700', '1400');
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $dates[] = strtotime("monday +$i weeks $hours[$i]");
}
```

If you need the `h` for the rest of the code, you can remove it for just this purpose:

```
$hours = array('16h30', '17h00', '14h00');
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $dates[] = strtotime("monday +$i weeks " . 
                         join('', explode('h', $hours[$i])));
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that you can do this with strtotime. I tried and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the [DateTime classes](http://www.php.net/datetime):-

```
/**
 * Get weekly repeating dates for an event
 *
 * Creates an array of date time objects one for each $week
 * starting at $startDate. Using the default value of 0 will return
 * an array with just the $startDate, a value of 1 will return an
 * array containing $startDate + the following week.
 *
 * @param DateTime $startDate
 * @param int optional defaults to 0 number of weeks to repeat
 * @return array of DateTime objects
 */
function getWeeklyOccurences(DateTime $startDate, $weeks = 0)
{
    $occurences = array();
    $period = new DatePeriod($startDate, new DateInterval('P1W'), $weeks);
    foreach($period as $date){
        $occurences[] = $date;
    }
    return $occurences;
}

$startDate = new datetime();
$startDate->setTime(16, 30);
var_dump(getWeeklyOccurences($startDate, 52));
```

Gives the following output:-

```
array (size=53)

      0 => 
        object(DateTime)[4]
          public 'date' => string '2012-11-06 16:30:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(DateTime)[5]
          public 'date' => string '2012-11-13 16:30:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      2 => 
        object(DateTime)[6]
          public 'date' => string '2012-11-20 16:30:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      3 => 
        object(DateTime)[7]
          public 'date' => string '2012-11-27 16:30:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

etc..

You can then format the output however you want using [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: Generate the first date using mktime and then use strtotime:

```
$start_date = mktime(16, 30, 0, 11, 5, 2012);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    // how to specify the hour $hours[$i] ?
    $dates[] = strtotime("+$i weeks 0 days", $start_date);
}
```

Comment: I had something similar in mind, but the solution of @mark is more elegant.